# Build Style item not exist in context menu in creating CSS file in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stylesheet, visual-studio-2013

I want to create a CSS file in Visual Studio 2013. but **Build Style** item not exist in context menu. how to get it?

[image]

my toolbar:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Style Builder dialog (aka New Style wizard) is deprecated.  It still exists in the WebForms editor (under Format -> New Style, but only after you've loaded design view), but not in the new HTML and CSS editors.

The reason for this is because the dialog depends on the (also deprecated) HTML Designer, and because it is very out of date.  Instead, you should consider writing your styles in the CSS editor, which has some better features (such as supporting CSS3, vendor prefixes, snippets, color picker, and several other editing improvements).

Comment: How do you get to the color picker when editing CSS? That's all I really ever used the "Build Style" dialog for anymore, anyway. I don't see a color picker anywhere when editing the CSS.

Comment: Whenever you use a hex color, you'll get the new picker.  It shows an MRU of colors, but expands down into a full on color picker.

Comment: I've got this to work exactly one time. But I don't remember how. I see the MRU of colors when I start typing a hex color, but then can't figure out how to open the color picker from there. This feature is WAY too hidden, apparently. It should be the first item in the MRU.

Comment: @CleverHuman the full color picker is at the far right end in a double down arrow.

Comment: The ability to save the new style (being built from Style builder dialog) into an existing stylesheet file is nice. Thanks for letting us know about the `Format` menu in VS which appears magically from no where the moment you open the `*.aspx` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I added `Build Style` in Visual Studio 2013 !

[image]

**This is how to add Style Sheet Toolbar**

[image]

Or

You can reference [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b12f4767-d12b-47b0-90da-98b6c0b588e8/build-style-css-dialog-disabled?forum=vseditor) link !

**Edit**

[Here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/visual-studio-2013-web-editor-features-css) is Visual Studio 2013 Web Editor Features - CSS , this may be a good reference for you !

Comment: what is name of this toolbar?

Comment: style sheet toolbar ... !

Comment: zey , my question edited. not exist style sheet toolbar